# Should I force vassalise my historical rival?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Playing as Byzantium, I have finally won my last war against the Ottomans and I can subdue their nation into a single province. I also have the option to make them my vassal. Having them as a subject can facilitate further conquests of Syria by feeding them conquered provinces and then integrating them later. The problem is that as a historical rival their liberty desire is 50 % higher than normal at all times and our relations are always 25 points lower.

Is it in my interest to vassalise them?

Comment: As @Alien-47 mentioned below, Syria is your best bet which will give you claims in Egypt as well. In case you didn't know this, keep an eye out on the Timurids and find a chance to grab some Persian cores. Release Persia and when the Timurids go tits up, there's a chance that Persia will get lots of land. But be warned that that will make them a strong and often unruly subject and really hard to integrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to conquer a single Syrian core and release them as a vassal. 50% liberty desire is a HUGE penalty. It's not worth it IMO

Answer (score 2):

There is also a financial motivation against it. Can I assume you have kicked them quite far to the east by now? In that case their capital is likely no longer in the Constantinople trade node. Feeding them provinces will mean that much more of the trade flowing from the East will get stuck in Aleppo.

I would just take the provinces, get the trade flowing and use the extra cash to hire better admin advisers. That way there's no need to take the long route.

In summary, no I also don't think it's worth vassilising them.